# RecyclerView inside fragment not scrolling in Android API 22

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a RecyclerView in a ScrollView inside a Fragment to display multiple notifications. On Android API 28 it's working perfectly, but on API 22 it's not scrolling, unless I close the fragment and open it again, then it shows the RecyclerView in the new position (as if I scrolled, it doesn't scroll while the fragment is shown).

I tried:

1- Changing the ScrollView to NestedScrollView

2- Removing the ScrollView completely and working with the RecyclerView only

3- Removing the onClickListeners of the RecyclerView elements

Here is the code for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />
```

Edit: I removed the scroll layout, but the problem still persists. I also tried it and it works perfectly on android API 23 and later. The scrolling only stops working on android API 22 and earlier.

I just tried leaving the recycler view on its own, and it's still not scrolling.

Comment: there is no need for the scroll view just use the RecyclerView directly inside the ConstraintLayout , and can u add the code of the RecyclerView setup inside your fragment to your question?

Comment: in scroll view all things in scroll view layout don't need to use linear layout again

Comment: I need the scroll view and linear view; I have other views that I removed to shorten the code. Both the scroll view and the recycler view aren't scrolling.

Comment: Try to put your RecyclerView in another view such as LinearLayout. Also, set the height and width to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in another file where I used the fragment, there was an AppBarLayout there which prevented the scrolling in older APIs for some reason.
Removed the AppBarLayout and it worked fine.

Edit: I found a better solution that didn't require removing AppBarLayout
Instead of hiding and unhiding the fragment normally, I used setVisibility(GONE/VISIVILE) and it also somehow worked.